# force arabic character to follow left to right order

Tags: html, css, unicode, arabic

I have a page with an amount and a currency symbol (unicode characters). I need the symbol to always be to the left of the amount. I've tried many things and no matter what the symbol appears on the right. Any ideas?

```
<span dir="ltr">&#x62f;&#x2e;&#x625;12.11</span>
```

Please don't answer something like "if the currency symbol is in Arabic it should be right to left". This is the business requirement I was handed and is non-negotiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well how about this?

`<span dir="ltr">&#x62f;&#x2e;&#x625; <span dir="ltr">12.11</span></span>`

Comment: it works thanks! I tried so many combinations of ltr and spans / divs and though I was going to have to resort to using a table <gasp/>.

Comment: well, the right way is the simplest one. good luck